# Where is the parachute?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA San Andreas a parachute would apear on your back the moment you boarded a plane. Now everytime I bail out of a plane I just fall to death. How does one aquire a parachute in GTA V?

Comment: Afaik, planes still have one. However, check ammu nation too.

Answer (score 3):

The Parachute can be found at the very beginning of the game. The parachute is located right next to the cable car exit on top of Mount Chilliad.

Jump off the mountain and press the <kbd>A</kbd> button on Xbox 360 / <kbd>X</kbd> button on PS3 / <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> button on PC to open the parachute and drift down the mountain.

Answer (score 3):

You will receive a parachute every time you enter an aircraft after a certain late game Trevor mission.
You can also buy a parachute from Ammu-Nation (might need to to couple of story missions before it unlocks).

Answer (score 2):

Parachutes can be purchased at Ammunation where it is at the top-left corner on the weapon wall.

A parachute can be equipped in the air (if you're free falling, not just a jump) by going to the gun wheel and looking at the top-left. After you select it press the Xbox `A` button or the PlayStation `X` button to activate the chute. Pressing the Xbox `Y` button or the PlayStation `△` button disconnects you from the chute, allowing you to fall freely again (to your death).